# Unpacking Argument Lists and Instantiating WTForms objects from web.py

Tags: python, argument-passing, web.py, wtforms

After a bit of searching, I've found that it's possible to instantiate a WTForms object in web.py using the following code:

```
form = my_form(**web.input())
```

web.input() returns a "dictionary-like" web.storage object, but without the double asterisks WTForms will raise an exception:

```
TypeError: formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper that supports the 'getlist' method
```

From the Python documentation I understand that the two asterisks are used to unpack a dictionary of named arguments. That said, I'm still a bit confused about exactly what is going on. What makes the web.storage object returned by web.input() "dictionary-like" enough that it can be unpacked by ** but *not* "dictionary-like" enough that it can be passed as-is to the WTForms constructor?

I know that this is an extremely basic question, but any advice to help a novice programmer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [WTForms source](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/7a1d35417546/wtforms/form.py):

```
def process(self, formdata=None, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if formdata is not None and not hasattr(formdata, 'getlist'):
        if hasattr(formdata, 'getall'):
            formdata = WebobInputWrapper(formdata)
        else:
            raise TypeError("formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper that supports the 'getlist' method")

    for name, field, in iteritems(self._fields):
        if obj is not None and hasattr(obj, name):
            field.process(formdata, getattr(obj, name))
        elif name in kwargs:
            field.process(formdata, kwargs[name])
        else:
            field.process(formdata)
```

You currently pass arguments as `**kwargs`, but if you want `formdata` to work, then it should be multidict-type that is not like a regular `dict` or webpy's `web.storage`, because both of them don't have `getlist` method. `multidict` is a dict that stores multiple values for the same key.

You may try to pass `web.input()` as `obj` argument, like this: `form = my_form(None, web.input())` I think it should work.

Comment: Ok, that was very helpful! After a bit of experimentation, I've found four ways of passing data to wtforms that seem to work equally well:
1. my_form(a='1', b='2') #passing form values as named parameters
2. my_form(**{'a':'1','b':'2'}) #same as 1, but w/ argument unpacking
3. my_form(MultiDict.UnorderedMultiDict(web.input().items())) #Forcing through a multi-dict
4. my_form(None, web.input()) #As you suggested
Thanks!

Comment: I was wrong about multidict, found correct explanation [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict).

Answer (score 3):

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  The difference is that doing `func(someDict)` passes one argument, namely a dict.  Doing `func(**someDict)` unpacks the dict and passes each key/value pair as a separate keyword argument.

The difference has nothing to with being "dict-like enough" or with different degrees of dict-like-ness.  (It also has nothing to with `web.py` or WTForms.)  The two options are simply two different ways that a function can be written to accept different sorts of arguments, and two corresponding ways to pass in those arguments.  Examples:

```
>> def oneArg(d):
...     print d
>>> def manyArgs(**d):
...     print d
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> oneArg(d)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> manyArgs(**d)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> manyArgs(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

The last two examples in particular show what `**d` does.  Passing a dict with `**d` is the same as passing each key/value pair as a separate keyword argument.

Comment: Thanks! OK, one more question: What is happening when the object that follows ** is a web.storage object and not a standard dict?